# What would happen if you opened a Bag of Holding underwater?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

I'm in a naval campaign where some of the game could take place underwater, and I could reasonably acquire a Bag of Holding soon, so it would be nice to know before I try to grab an item underwater and jettison all of my gear into the Astral plane. Would it fill with water until the bag was filled to capacity and scatter all the contents inside as well?

Also assuming you didn't break the Bag of Holding by overfilling it to capacity, would putting water inside it get other objects inside wet, potentially ruining them?

Comment: I'm interested how the answer changes if you open it upside down without letting things fall out.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It would quickly* rupture.

[Five-hundred pounds of water is only about 8 cubic feet in volume](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=500%20pounds%20of%20water%20in%20cubic%20feet), so the bag's weight capacity would be overloaded after merely an eighth of its volume capacity was reached — assuming it started empty, as any other items in it would help it reach its weight limit earlier. It would then rupture, scattering its (damp or soaked) contents across the Astral sea.

An objection might be raised: doesn't the bag only store things specifically *put* into it? No, the owner is not so in control. There's no verbiage limiting access to only *intentionally* stored items, so an open bag allows anything to pass into it. This means that opening it underwater would result in the water pouring in.

The space inside the bag is described as a continuous finite volume, not a set of pocket-spaces for each individual item put in it; therefore, putting/letting water into it would get water on any other items sitting inside.

<sub>* How quickly depends on the local water pressure, but just “quickly” is plenty of precision for our purposes.</sub>

Comment: Anyone who wants to debate how physics applies to D&D magic items beyond simple encumbrance, *good luck* and please use [this chat room for the purpose](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39096/discussion-on-answer-by-sevensideddie-what-would-happen-if-you-opened-a-bag-of-h). Anyone who has suggestions for how this answer can be improved, feel free to use comments for that. Thanks!

Comment: 8 cubic feet of water while underwater weigh virtually nothing, weight is not  the same as mass. just don't leave the water with the bag foll of water.

Comment: @John If the pressure of the outside water were pressing on and equalising the internal pressure of the bag (creating neutral buoyancy), but that’s not what’s happening. The extradimensional space that is the “inside” of the bag is another plane of existence—a pocket dimension—and is not itself underwater. The weight capacity of the bag’s extradimensional space is unaffected by where its portal-item is, and the weight limit will still be exceeded.

Comment: @John The way the item-dimension combination works regarding weight is explicitly defined by its having a weight limit. See also the first comment under this answer.

Answer (score 30):

Nothing in the rules says the bag would keep the water out, so water would *probably* flood the bag.

*On the other hand*, nothing in the rules says that the air pressure in the bag is always 1 atmosphere. It is entirely possible that the inside of the bag magically matches the pressure of its surroundings.

If you want to be "nice", you could rule that the players are allowed to open the bag upside down (essentially turning it into a diver's bell) and blindly fish around for their items.

Comment: If you turn it upside down, won't all the items fall out?

Comment: @immibis Quite possibly. The character would have to make a small opening and hold it closed around their hand. Not an easy task, for sure.

Comment: Items in a bag of holding can't exit a bag of holding unless the user thinks about them, at which time they find themselves holding the object they were thinking about (provided it was in the bag to start with).  So to pull out an item while the bag is upside down is no more challenging than pulling it out when it's right side up.

Comment: @Shem I think that was true in older editions, but I don't see anything like that in the 5e listing.

Comment: @immibis The description of the item covers that: no, its contents only fall out if you turn the bag inside out.

Comment: @Shem I think that's the [handy haversack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53131/handy-haversack-vs-bag-of-holding) you're thinking of.

Comment: Diving bell and atmospheric pressure! +1 :)

Answer (score 11):

There is no fundamental difference between it filing with water and exploding and filling with air and exploding.

It is absolutely clear that the whole point of a bag of holding is that normal physics don't apply and that it's a convenient in-game way to be able to carry lots of stuff.

Having said that the idea that the magic mag treat water as different from air is not utterly unreasonable but then again if you are magically breathing underwater  in the first place....

Probably the sensible thing is to have the DM adjudicate whether a) a normal bag of holding will work in the world they have devised b) whether a special underwater bag of holding is possible c) they may want you to test it in-game for yourself

Comment: This answer essentially boils down to "your dm should do whatever they want"; which is sometimes an appropriate answer, but this answer seems to be trying to pretend that's not what it's saying. It doesn't make any appeal to any rules, tries to make some kind of argument from a physics standpoint but then says physics doesn't apply. There IS a fundamental difference between filling it with air and with water (the weight), which is a relevant difference to both physics and the rules.

Comment: I believe that the water/air equivalence was referring to the fact that opening the bag (allowing it to fill with ambient air) doesn't overfill the bag, causing it to rupture.  With that in mind, why would allowing the bag to fill with ambient water cause it to rupture?  Would opening it during a dust storm cause it to rupture as it over-filled with dust/sand?  Or does it take an active attempt to put more into the bag than it can handle to cause it to rupture?

Comment: The issue with water is that it is heavy.  If you fill it with air or dusty wind, it's still under the weight limit.  If you fill it with water, it hits the weight limit pretty quickly, and it's the weight limit that causes it to rupture.  "do you hit the weight limit or not" is a pretty fundamental difference for something with a hard-coded weight limit.

Answer (score 3):

In-game, ask the Bag's vendor to answer, and to prove their answer with a test. That way the GM can answer with their own 'physicks'.

Comment: Even uncommon magic items are worth over 100gp. I'm not sure the shopkeeper would want to risk destroying one.

Comment: Could be the start of a quest to find a conman selling "waterproof" bags of holding.

Answer (score 2):

When you are underwater its best to treat the water itself like air when it comes to taking up space. It will fill the bag when you open it, but it doesn't affect its capacity until you cross over onto land again where you'll have to dump the water out. Water wouldn't rupture the bag any more than air would. Water does not continually force itself in until it bursts, it simply fills the bag as it would fill any container. I might have the player who opens it underwater for the first time without being careful make a save to avoid being pulled inside by the sudden suction of the water rushing in, but that's about it. I would also say the items inside would get wet. It is one pocket plane so its not compartmentalized like a handy haversack would be. Anything like paper would get ruined instantly. Magic items and things in sealed containers would be fine.