# Is a bag of holding waterproof?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

Are the contents of a bag of holding (such as scrolls) safe from water damage while inside it when the bag is immersed in water?

Comment: [Related about opening the bag underwater (5e)](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/79458/9625)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the [d20pfsrd.com entry](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/bag-of-holding):

> If living creatures are placed within the bag, they can survive for up to 10 minutes, after which time they suffocate.

If you can suffocate in the bag, it is air tight.  If it is air tight, it must be water tight.  (Though, presumably, both of these conditions are incumbent upon the bag being closed.)

Comment: Those conditions **are** incumbent on it being closed.  [Opening a bag of holding underwater (where the volume of the body of water is more than the bag can hold) will destroy the bag nearly instantly.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79458/what-would-happen-if-you-opened-a-bag-of-holding-underwater)

Comment: This doesn't necessarily follow -- a slow leak might not give you enough air to survive, but would eventually allow in enough water to damage paper. It is not true that any container in which you can suffocate, is water-tight. But the fact that you can suffocate in what appears to be a common cloth sack certainly does mean that when it's closed it's magically sealed. The only remaining question is whether that seal is perfect, or lies in the "zone of annoyance" that suffocates without completely protecting the contents.

Comment: @LegendaryDude That's debatable. There's no "word of God" on the issue, and the second-most upvoted answer takes the opposite opinion.