# Can a Thief rogue use the Fast Hands feature to draw something from a magic item as a bonus action?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, class-feature, rogue, thief

My DM gave me a magic little bag, [*Heward's handy spice pouch*](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Heward%27s_handy_spice_pouch), which has the description:

> Someone holding the pouch could reach into it and speak the name of any type of nonmagical seasoning—salt, pepper, saffron etc.—and produce enough of that seasoning to apply to a single meal. This power could be used up to ten times until the pouch recovered its magic at the next dawn.

I've read that you can't use an object that requires an action to use/activate, but that item does not require an action (and don't need to get activated neither) and we've ruled it produces enough for a single meal, but does not requires to *be* applied on a meal. Which means it's basically the same thing as taking an item from a *bag of holding*.

I wanted to be able to draw pepper as an action and a bonus action, that way I would be able throw pepper in someone's eyes on my next turn.

*Heward's handy spice pouch* does not seem to specify if it needs *an action* to be used.

Comment: Related: "[How many turns does it take to grab an item from a bag of holding and throw it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/89824)" and "[What items can a Thief use as a bonus action with his Fast Hands?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72270)"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### The *spice pouch* requires an action, so it doesn't work with Fast Hands

The description of [*Heward's handy spice pouch*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/hewards-handy-spice-pouch) says:

> While holding the pouch, you can use an action to expend 1 of its charges, speak the name of any nonmagical food seasoning [...]
>
> — *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, p. 137

That action is a special action option given by the magic item (such actions are often grouped as Use Magic Object), which is distinct from the Use an Object action; this special action can't be taken as a bonus action using Fast Hands. See the rules on [activating a magic item](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/magic-items#ActivatinganItem):

> If an item requires an action to activate, that action isn't a function of the Use an Item action, so a feature such as the rogue's Fast Hands can't be used to activate the item.
>
> — *Dungeon Master's Guide*, p. 141

Comment: It looks like OP's quote is taken directly from the paraphrased description on the [FR wiki page for the item](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Heward%27s_handy_spice_pouch), rather than using the description of the item from *Xanathar's*.